# how to use leiningen to download dependenies for the openimaj library

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to use the repository specified in:

http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/

and the metadata is here:
http://maven.ecs.soton.ac.uk/content/groups/maven.openimaj.org/org/openimaj/openimaj/maven-metadata.xml

the project is defined:

```
(defproject imaj "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :repositories [["openimaj" "http://maven.openimaj.org"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.openimaj/openimaj "1.1"]])
```

but when I do a `lein deps`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find artifact openimaj:openimaj:jar:1.1 in openimaj (http://maven.openimaj.org)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong dependency?

They use a modular approach, so you have the different dependencies core, image, video, math, etc.

You could try including the modules you need?

```
[org.openimaj/core "1.0.5"]
```

The documentation available at http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/ has more details.

Looking around the repository they do have the org.openimaj/openimaj directory, so what you have should work.

Comment: yeah. I figured it out... you have to add it like this: [org.openimaj/core-image "1.1"], [org.openimaj/core-video "1.1"]... etc...